# How do I remove pause from controlbar of youtube videos?

Tags: youtube-api

I have a page with an embedded youtube video.  I want to keep part of the control bar - the part that shows progress and that the user can drag back and forth.  But I don't want to keep the pause/play feature of the control bar.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you a Youtube Javascript API if you can play and stopping and video from code at the events that you want! See the docs...